# Error: render function or template not defined in component using Element UI documentation example

Tags: vuejs2

I'm a new to VueJS Element UI and front end in general.
Unfortunately, I didn't find out any useful documentation about how to use Element UI. So I try by myself some of the example available on Element UI website. And it appear that some of them doesn't work. Here's an example

http://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/container

with

> Error: render function or template not defined in component

```
<el-container style="height: 500px; border: 1px solid #eee">
  <el-aside width="200px" style="background-color: rgb(238, 241, 246)">
    <el-menu :default-openeds="['1', '3']">
      <el-submenu index="1">
        <template slot="title"><i class="el-icon-message"></i>Navigator One</template>
        <el-menu-item-group>
          <template slot="title">Group 1</template>
          <el-menu-item index="1-1">Option 1</el-menu-item>
          <el-menu-item index="1-2">Option 2</el-menu-item>
        </el-menu-item-group>
        <el-menu-item-group title="Group 2">
          <el-menu-item index="1-3">Option 3</el-menu-item>
        </el-menu-item-group>
        <el-submenu index="1-4">
          <template slot="title">Option4</template>
          <el-menu-item index="1-4-1">Option 4-1</el-menu-item>
        </el-submenu>
      </el-submenu>
      <el-submenu index="2">
        <template slot="title"><i class="el-icon-menu"></i>Navigator Two</template>
        <el-menu-item-group>
          <template slot="title">Group 1</template>
          <el-menu-item index="2-1">Option 1</el-menu-item>
          <el-menu-item index="2-2">Option 2</el-menu-item>
        </el-menu-item-group>
        <el-menu-item-group title="Group 2">
          <el-menu-item index="2-3">Option 3</el-menu-item>
        </el-menu-item-group>
        <el-submenu index="2-4">
          <template slot="title">Option 4</template>
          <el-menu-item index="2-4-1">Option 4-1</el-menu-item>
        </el-submenu>
      </el-submenu>
      <el-submenu index="3">
        <template slot="title"><i class="el-icon-setting"></i>Navigator Three</template>
        <el-menu-item-group>
          <template slot="title">Group 1</template>
          <el-menu-item index="3-1">Option 1</el-menu-item>
          <el-menu-item index="3-2">Option 2</el-menu-item>
        </el-menu-item-group>
        <el-menu-item-group title="Group 2">
          <el-menu-item index="3-3">Option 3</el-menu-item>
        </el-menu-item-group>
        <el-submenu index="3-4">
          <template slot="title">Option 4</template>
          <el-menu-item index="3-4-1">Option 4-1</el-menu-item>
        </el-submenu>
      </el-submenu>
    </el-menu>
  </el-aside>

  <el-container>
    <el-header style="text-align: right; font-size: 12px">
      <el-dropdown>
        <i class="el-icon-setting" style="margin-right: 15px"></i>
        <el-dropdown-menu slot="dropdown">
          <el-dropdown-item>View</el-dropdown-item>
          <el-dropdown-item>Add</el-dropdown-item>
          <el-dropdown-item>Delete</el-dropdown-item>
        </el-dropdown-menu>
      </el-dropdown>
      <span>Tom</span>
    </el-header>

    <el-main>
      <el-table :data="tableData">
        <el-table-column prop="date" label="Date" width="140">
        </el-table-column>
        <el-table-column prop="name" label="Name" width="120">
        </el-table-column>
        <el-table-column prop="address" label="Address">
        </el-table-column>
      </el-table>
    </el-main>
  </el-container>
</el-container>

<style>
  .el-header {
    background-color: #B3C0D1;
    color: #333;
    line-height: 60px;
  }

  .el-aside {
    color: #333;
  }
</style>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      const item = {
        date: '2016-05-02',
        name: 'Tom',
        address: 'No. 189, Grove St, Los Angeles'
      };
      return {
        tableData: Array(20).fill(item)
      }
    }
  };
</script>
```

Comment: Seems to work fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/fppspye3/

Comment: Hi @Terry, on the official website, there's also a link to jsfiddle and I compare your setting with the official website's setting and it appear that  your 'load type' parameter is set to 'onLoad'. (Don't know what is it yet) and do you think that there's something I have to set up before try this code on a localhost ?

Comment: It just decides when to run the JS: in that fiddle (which I forked from ElementUI's official example), the JS is executed after `body.onLoad` has been fired. You should try to create an MCVE, since your code is proven to work. See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal, concrete and verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @S7_0, please, see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your component is the wrong syntax. See [doc](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html)

just wrap all HTML in `<template></template>` tag like this:

```
<template>
    <el-container style="height: 500px; border: 1px solid #eee">
        <!-- some code -->
    </el-container>
</template>
```